# Do quest levels scale with player level?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've played and completed the Witcher 3 (only the main story and some sidequests) when it released. I've wanted to go back ever since, but there is one thing holding me back: outlevelling quests.

AFAIK patch 1.2 added scaling enemies, thus the quests will remain challenging no matter the order in which you do them. Also I think that this does not affect quest rewards.

Is there any mod that also scales the rewards, so that they are always relative?

If not, is there some quest order online that I can follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to scale quests or their rewards to your level.

It wouldn't really make sense narrative-wise if delivering a pan got you 2000 gold and a rare Witcher sword, would it?

Since side quests rarely affect the main story (typically ones involving major characters from the books), just do side quests in order of ascending recommended level. If you're already way past some quests' recommended levels, just do them in whatever order you feel like. The easier quests typically won't take nearly as long as the later quests, anyways.